# How to redirect url by a value in laravel by controller?

Tags: php, laravel, url, redirect

Is it possible to redirect to a url by a value from controller like the one we do in route?

Route example:

```
Route::get('/anyUrl/{id}', 'controller@function');
```

But how to do it in controller?
I mean how to pass the id by url in controller?

```
return redirect('/anyUrl/{$id}');
```

Something like above

Comment: `return redirect("/anyUrl/$id");`

Comment: your `id` recieve by controller method automatically, just `return redirect("/anyUrl/{$id}");`

Comment: This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
return Redirect::to('/anyUrl/'. $id);
```

Comment: return redirect("/anyUrl/$id"); This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Comment: @hekmat: Thanks and Glad to help :)

Comment: it's a right way. but don't forget that best way to call routes is naming theme. as a suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This should redirect you with your `id`:

```
return redirect("/anyUrl/$id");
```

Comment: This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/anyUrl/{id}', 'controller@function');
```

> Surely it helps you

```
public function yourFunctionName($id){
   return Redirect::to('/anyUrl/'.$id)
}
```

Comment: return redirect("/anyUrl/$id"); This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Comment: If it works then accept my answer bro have a great day

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/anyUrl/{id}', 'controller@function');
```

in your controller receive like this way.

```
public function yourFunctionName($id){
   dd($id);
}

 return redirect("your url");
/anyUrl/$id
```

Comment: return redirect("/anyUrl/$id"); This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
return Redirect::route('user', array('nick' => $username));
```

Comment: return redirect("/anyUrl/$id");
 This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Comment: did u try my solution? Is another approach

Comment: right now no, the one i commented is more simple i think. but thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

your id automatically sending into controller, just fetch that by `request helper` or by `method argument` and then `return redirect("anyUrl/{$id}");`

Comment: return redirect("/anyUrl/$id"); This worked, i used single quotation but it works with double quotation. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy to redirect on a route. at first, you can add route name. example

```
Route::get('/anyUrl/{id}', 'controller@function')->name('profile');
```

then you can redirect by route name.

```
return Redirect()->Route('profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route has parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the route method:

// For a route with the following URI: demo/{id}

return redirect()->route('demo', ['id' => 1]);